# Edit shared preferences using repeating alarm

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am trying to change one key of the shared preferences file at the end of the day. So here is what I managed to find on the internet:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, AlarmResetFoodAdded.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
if (!alarmUp) {
    setAlarm();
}
```

Function setAlarm():

```
private void setAlarm() {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmResetFoodAdded.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

AlarmResetFoodAdded.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(AppControl.PREF, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefEditor = pref.edit();

    prefEditor.putInt("foodAdded", 0);
    prefEditor.commit();
}
```

I am testing this using the device simulator with API 28. I tried to set the time to about 13:59. Then I'd wait until about 14:01 because it is inExactRepeating, but the key foodAdded in the preferences file stay the same, even when I reopen the app.

I'm pretty sure the alarm is up because when I debug alarmUp, the value is false the first time, then when I reopen it, it is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `prefEditor.apply();` instead of `prefEditor.commit();` in your onReceive method.